# multiple conditions with while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I am having problems including multiple statements with `while` loop in python. It works perfectly fine with single condition but when i include multiple conditions, the loop does not terminate. Am i doing something wrong here?

```
name = raw_input("Please enter a word in the sentence (enter . ! or ? to end.)")

final = list()

while (name != ".") or (name != "!") or (name != "?"):
    final.append(name)
    print "...currently:", " ".join(final)
    name = raw_input("Please enter a word in the sentence (enter . ! or ? to end.)")
print " ".join(final)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `and`; you want the loop to continue if *all* conditions are met, not just one:

```
while (name != ".") and (name != "!") and (name != "?"):
```

You don't need the parentheses however.

Better would be to test for membership here:

```
while name not in '.!?':
```

Answer (score 2):

This condition:

```
(name != ".") or (name != "!") or (name != "?")
```

is always true. It could only be false of all three subconditions were false, which would require that
`name` were equal to `"."` and `"!"` and `"?"` simultaneously.

You mean:

```
while (name != ".") and (name != "!") and (name != "?"):
```

or, more simply,

```
while name not in { '.', '!', '?' }:
```