# While loop continues infinitely even after condition is satisfied

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

Here is a loop to make sure players of my small game input valid answers but the while loop conintues infinitely, even when the conditions are satisfied to break the loop:

```
initialize = ''
    while initialize != 'yes' or initialize != 'no':
        print('\nWould you like to play?')
        initialize = input('Yes or No? ').lower().strip()
        if initialize == 'yes':
            print('\nHappy to see you.\n')
        elif initialize == 'no':
            print('\nNo worries.\n\nThanks for stopping by!') 
        else:
            print('\nSorry, I didn\'t catch that')
print('please wait as game loads')
print('\nYou\'re very important to us\n')
```

if 'yes' or 'no' is typed in the correct if statement runs but the loop continues:
Would you like to play?
Yes or No? yes

Happy to see you.

Would you like to play?
Yes or No?

Comment: Your while condition is equivalent to `not (initialize == 'yes' and initialize == 'no')` ([De Morgan's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2168630/4859885)). In this form, it's clear to see why it loops indefinitely.

Comment: Related:[multiple conditions with while loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578277/multiple-conditions-with-while-loop-in-python).

Answer (score 4):

You don't want `or`, you want `and`, since it will always be unequal to one of the two:

```py
initialize = 'yes' # start it off with something valid so the loop runs
while initialize != 'yes' and initialize != 'no':
    print('\nWould you like to play?')
    initialize = input('Yes or No? ').lower().strip()
    if initialize == 'yes':
        print('\nHappy to see you.\n')
    elif initialize == 'no':
        print('\nNo worries.\n\nThanks for stopping by!') 
    else:
        print('\nSorry, I didn\'t catch that')
```

Alternatively, use `not in`:

```py
while initialize not in ['yes', 'no']:
    # code goes here
```

Comment: I wanted to comment this answer just now, but you did it first so I'm upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very quick and dirty hack

```
initialize = ''


while initialize == '':
    print('\nWould you like to play?')
    initialize = input('Yes or No? ').lower().strip()
    if initialize == 'yes':
        print('\nHappy to see you.\n')
    elif initialize == 'no':
        print('\nNo worries.\n\nThanks for stopping by!')
    else:
        print('\nSorry, I didn\'t catch that')
        
print('please wait as game loads')
print('\nYou\'re very important to us\n')
```

The problem with your code was that the evaluation in the `while` bit is wrong.